# I have require multi items Carousel in angular 2

Tags: angular, carousel

I have find Carousel in angular2. but, i don't get multi items carousel in angular2.

I have require multi items Carousel With **swipe** support for **draggable** in angular 2. **not using Jquery**.

I have add one screen shot for my required Carousel.

[image]

Answer (score 10):

try NgPrime, it's a big and mature library:
https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/carousel

this is angular2 catalog, you can search there also:
https://github.com/brillout/awesome-angular-components#carousel

Comment: if support with drag ?

Comment: I am not sure, I added another link for angular 2 catalog. you can search there

Comment: Any Idea about how to customize the styling of NgPrime carousel ??

Comment: you have styleClass property on every PrimeNg control, so does the carousel. moreover you can create your own theme or modify an existing theme.

Comment: NgPrime is not drag-supported

Answer (score 1):

Hi i have used ng bootstrap and created one carousal with mat card  u can get it from below github path

[Github-angular-carousal](https://github.com/lijoos/angular-carousal)

**Please see the hosted sample** [Here](https://angular-carousal.firebaseapp.com/)

[image]