# how to fix carosel item numbers to display?

Tags: css, angular, bootstrap-4, mdbootstrap

i have a question i am developing an angular app so i have a task i have 5 cards btw i am using mdbootstrap so as i said i have 5 card and i want to display them using carousel but the idea is i want to display the 5 cards one time in the big screens and use that carousel only in mobile sizes but the carousel only display one card despite my card's width is very small does any one have any idea how to do this ? and thank you

my cards code

```
 <div class="d-flex flex-column justify-content-end buttomdivheight" >
       <div class="d-flex justify-content-between" >
         <div class="d-flex flex-column align-self-end">
          <span class="bottomtoptitles assesscolor" style="font-size: 0.8em">Projects  </span>
          <span class="bottomtoptitles assesscolor" style="font-size: 0.8em">to evaluate:</span>
          <span class="bottombottomnumber assesscolorbottombackground"> 0/30</span>
         </div>
         <div  class="d-flex flex-column">
          <br>
          <span class="bottomtoptitles assesscolor">Starts in:</span>
          <span class="bottombottomnumber assesscolorbottombackground">00:00:00:00</span>
         </div>
       </div>
  </div>
```

and carousel link https://mdbootstrap.com/docs/angular/advanced/carousel/

Comment: Does it work to have the cards without the carousel for big screens, and with the carousel for the Mobile screens?

Comment: mmmmm i dont know may be ill do it like that with ngif but the task use the carousel

Comment: You can check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43252908/5613720

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [NgPrime carousel](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/carousel) as it is more flexible.

Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43252908/5613720